# Laravel 4 custom commands not being found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, command, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create a custom command in Laravel using php artisan but although I did everything that is written in here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands including the registration of the command, it is still not being listed in the commands list when I type php artisan.

This is the command:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class PremiumSets extends Command {
    protected $name = 'sets:check';
    protected $description = 'Check if any of the users did not select a premium set.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        Log::error("PremiumSets Here");
    }

    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
?>
```

The \app\start\artisan.php (I tried using the Artisan::resolve() as well but it still didn't work)

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Artisan Commands
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each available Artisan command must be registered with the console so
| that it is available to be called. We'll register every command so
| the console gets access to each of the command object instances.
|
*/

Artisan::add(new PremiumSets);
```

Comment: Did you try running `composer dump`?

Comment: And what is the file location and filename of your command?

Comment: I tried the composer dump, still no luck. The location is \app\commands\PremiumSets.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found! Make sure you don't have this code in your routes.php:

Artisan::call('up');

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the full path in your \app\start\artisan.php  like:

Artisan::add(new App\Commands\PremiumSets);